# AVR uint8_t doesn't get correct value

Tags: c, embedded, avr, avr-gcc

I have a uint8_t that should contain the result of a bitwise calculation. The debugger says the variable is set correctly, but when i check the memory, the var is always at 0. The code proceeds like the var is 0, no matter what the debugger tells me. Here's the code:

```
temp = (path_table & (1 << current_bit)) >> current_bit;
//temp is always 0, debugger shows correct value
if (temp > 0) {
    DS18B20_send_bit(pin, 0x01);
} else {
    DS18B20_send_bit(pin, 0x00);
}
```

Temp's a `uint8_t`, path_table's a `uint64_t` and current_bit's a `uint8_t`. I've tried to make them all uint64_t but nothing changed. I've also tried using unsigned long long int instead. Nothing again.

The code always enters the else clause.
Chip's Atmega4809, and uses uint64_t in other parts of the code with no issues.

Note - If anyone knows a more efficient/compact way to extract a single bit from a variable i would really appreciate if you could share ^^

Comment: What are the values of `path_table` and `current_bit`?

Comment: And why the right shift if you just want to know if a bit is set? `if (path_table & (1 << current_bit)) { ... }` would be more idiomatic.

Comment: And why the subsequent conditional when you could write the resulting `0` or `1` straight to the port?

Comment: @WeatherVane Ooo, clever.

Comment: And what is the *type* of `path_table`?

Comment: path_table value is 0xF200042C7199FF28 and current_bit is 16 when this problem arises. Also, the code has been slightly modified in the past few hours to make tests, the original was like Shawn's. EDIT path_table's an uint64_t, as in the question.

Comment: What size is the machine's `int`?

Comment: What value is `INT_MAX`?

Comment: Try changing `1 << current_bit` to `1ull << current_bit`.

Comment: Or you could do `temp = (path_table >> current_bit) & 1;` if you want a 0 or 1 value.

Comment: Atmega4809 int should be 8bit. INT_MAX should then be 255. Tried to change 1<<current_bit to 1ull<<current_bit and no change. I've also tried another board with the same chip, no change.

Comment: `int` is 8-bit? It needs to be at least 16-bits to be standard.

Comment: Sorry double checked and it's 16b, not 8b.

Comment: `1ull` should support left shifts of at least 63 to be standard.

Comment: that's a guessing game.

Comment: @IanAbbott Telling someone to use 64 bit arithmetic on an AVR isn't brilliant advise.

Comment: @Lundin They're already using 64-bit arithmetic. `path_table` is a `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1` is an integer constant, of type `int`.  The expression `1 << current_bit` also has type `int`, but for 16-bit `int`, the result of that expression is undefined when `current_bit` is larger than 14.  The behavior being undefined in your case, then, it is plausible that your debugger presents results for the overall expression that seem inconsistent with the observed behavior.  If you used an `unsigned int` constant instead, *i.e.* `1u`, then the resulting value of temp would be well defined as 0 whenever `current_bit` was greater than 15, because the result of the left shift would be zero.

Solve this problem by performing the computation in a type wide enough to hold the result.  Here's a compact, correct, and pretty clear way to correct your code to do that:

```
DS18B20_send_bit(pin, (path_table & (((uint64_t) 1) << current_bit)) != 0);
```

Or if `path_table` has an unsigned type then I prefer this, though it's more of a departure from your original:

```
DS18B20_send_bit(pin, (path_table >> current_bit) & 1);
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but i've already tried changing all variables to 64b unsigned and it still didn't work. EDIT - The right shift somehow works

Comment: @Crystallize, changing the types of your *variables* seems unlikely to be effective, because, as this answer already describes, the problem is with the type of your *constant*.

Comment: Answer's been marked as accepted since the due to the suggestion to use a right shift the problem has been now solved. Constant are the default ones provided by Atmel and honestly i don't see anything strange, as uint64_t is defined as unsigned long long int (As it should be, if i'm not mistaken). Also the right shift suggestion already came from Ian Abbott but i cannot accept a comment as an answer... sorry Ian ^^

Comment: @Crystallize, the *constant* involved is `1`.  Which has type `int`.  Which is the problem with your original code, as this answer explains.  This is why both Ian and I asked, in different ways, about the size of your machine's `int`s.

Comment: This has been tagged AVR since the start. Telling someone to cast to uint64_t on an AVR is pretty much like telling someone to go install Windows 10 on a 486 computer.

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer to write as `path_table & (((uint64_t)1) << current_bit)`.

Comment: @Lundin, the OP's `path_table` variable has type `uint64_t` and evidently uses all 64 bits.  They are performing 64-bit arithmetic in any case.

Comment: Fair enough, @NateEldredge.  Updated.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sorry i explained myself incorrectly. I did change the constant 1 to 1ull as well as all other elements with no effect.

Comment: @JohnBollinger So call him out and say that installing Windows 10 on a 486 isn't a brilliant idea. I made a separate call for sanity answer...

Answer (score 3):

Realization #1 here is that AVR is 1980-1990s technology core. It is not a x64 PC that chews 64 bit numbers for breakfast, but an extremely inefficient 8-bit MCU. As such:

- It likes 8 bit arithmetic.
- It will struggle with 16 bit arithmetic, by doing tricks with 16 bit index registers, double accumulators or whatever 8 bit core tricks it prefers to do.
- It will literally take ages to execute 32 bit arithmetic, by invoking software libraries inline.
- It will probably melt through the floor if attempting 64 bit arithmetic.

Before you do anything else, you need to get rid of all 64 bit arithmetic and radically minimize the use of 32 bit arithmetic. Period. There should be no single variable of `uint64_t` in your code or you are doing it very very wrong.

---

With this revelation also comes that all 8 bit MCUs always have an `int` type which is 16 bits.

In the code `1<<current_bit`, the integer constant `1` is of type `int`. Meaning that if `current_bit` is 15 or larger, you will shift bits into the sign bit of this temporary `int`. This is always a bug. Strictly speaking this is undefined behavior. In practice, you might end up with random change of sign of your numbers.

To avoid this, never use any form of bitwise operators on signed numbers. When mixing integer constants such as `1` with bitwise operators, change them to `1u` to avoid bugs like the one mentioned.

---

> If anyone knows a more efficient/compact way to extract a single bit from a variable i would really appreciate if you could share

The most efficient way in C is: `uint8_t variable; ... if(variable & (1u << bits))`. This should translate to the relevant "branch if bit set" instruction.

---

My general advise would be find your tool chain's disassembler and see what machine code that the C code actually generated. You don't have to be an assembler guru to read it, peeking at the [instruction set](https://www.microchip.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_instruction_list.html) should be enough.